# How to retrieve form fields in php if the data sent contains more than the form

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a simple form in which the user can enter a search term:

```
<form class="form-inline justify-content-center" id="searchForm">
      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only text-info" for="searchTerm">Search term</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Search">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
</form>
```

And I send the form using ajax like this:

```
$form = $(e.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: "searchmovielist.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {form: $form.serialize(), username: getCookie('username')},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

My question is how do I retrieve the fields from the form in php if I get the form using `$_GET['form']`?

Comment: Did you try to do `print_r($_GET)` to see what is the data received ?

Comment: `$_GET["form"]["searchTerm"]` will do it I would have thought, if the data is sent correctly. But you can just var_dump the GET array to see its structure and double-check. It's possible that you need to use serializeArray(), or something else, on the client-side though, because I think you're just assigning the "form" variable to be a string of url-encoded characters. Again you can easily check by watching your browser's network tab. Use the tools at your disposal to see what is actually happening. You don't have to guess blindly.

Comment: I have tried `$form = $_GET['form']` and then `$search = $form['searchTerm']` and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP function [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to split the string to array. So the code would be like

```
$username = $_GET['username']
parse_str($_GET['form'], $form_data);
var_dump($form_data);
```

But I'm wondering why are you reading username from a cookie and then sending it again in the request? Why not just read it from $_COOKIE in PHP?

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm reading the username from a cookie because the php in on the same server as the website only when testing and when deploying they are on different servers

Comment: Ok, makes sense to read the cookie this way them. So does parse_str function do what you need? If so, please accept the answer.